# Drupal7 on localhost going to index of /drupal7 instead

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I recently inserted the drupal 7 files into a folder in my localhost root.  After extracting them, I made a mysql database and was able to successfully install drupal 7, by typing localhost in my address bar, and navigating to the appropriate folder.  This worked very well.

Something unknown happened yesterday, and now when I go to the same place in the address bar (localhost/drupal7/), the drupal homepage no longer comes up.  Instead, I get the Index of /drupal7 page.  There is the index.php file that I can click on, and when I do, I am able to get to my drupal homepage.  But now all the links there (such as dashboard, content, etc.) only lead back to the generic Index of /drupal7.  This is insane.  I have no idea what could have changed to make this happen.

Comment: Please help!  If I used the wrong tag for this, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I installed XAMPP and used their BitNami stack to get Drupal going, so I guess the problem is solved.  I'm still baffled as to why it broke earlier.